# perl scipt:syntax error of unexpected token while spawing bash command using expect module

Tags: perl, expect

I am writing perl script to copy a directory to remote machine.
I am using an expect module to expect the password and send password.

But getting a syntax error as below

> sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `scp'
>
>   sh: -c: line 0:`system(scp -r /home/user1/data/ 192.168.0.1:/tmp/)'

perl script is:

```
use Expect;  
$Expect::Debug=2;

$cmd="scp -r /home/user1/data/ 192.168.0.1:/tmp/";

my $exp1=Expect-> spawn("system($cmd)") or die print "cannot spwan process\n";


$exp1-> expect(10,["root@192.168.0.1's password: "=>sub{ $exp1-> send("usr1234\r");}]);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't you just want `spawn($cmd)` instead of `spawn("system($cmd)")` ?

Comment: spawn($cmd) is not giving the error..

Comment: As soon as I execute this script putting on a debug root@192.168.0.1's password: Waiting for new data (10 seconds)...       is appearing ..at this point it doesn't get any data....so the password isn't send...   can you help me on this....leeduhem

Comment: error is not appearing again, but expect couldn't send the password now..as string it supposed to expect is already appeared even before it started expecting....

Comment: That should not happen. If the output appears on the console it normally means, that `Expect` is done with it. For example if the object is destructed or if you explicitly empty the handle. I would assume that it is matched immediately but your sub fails to do what you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what goes wrong in your script (execpt for the `spawn(system($cmd))` of course, but that is solved in the comments already. Maybe the `=>` is not needed? Or you need to end the password with `\n` instead of `\r`? Anyways, it is quite simple minded. I used something like the following to great effect (note that `$rsync` is my Expect object).

```
    $rsync=Expect->spawn ("rsync $remUser\@$remIp:$remFiles $locFolder");

    if (! defined($rsync))
    {
        die "spawning failed. Probably fork failed: $!";
    }

    my $matchStatus = $rsync->expect(100, '-re', '(.+)');

    if (! defined $matchStatus)
    {
        die "Nothing got returned within 100 seconds. $!";
    }

    my $spawned = 0;
    while ($spawned eq 0)
    {
        my $return = $rsync->match();

        if ($return =~ m/command not found/)
        {
            die "Command not found, there appears to be no rsync... $!";
        }
        elsif ($return =~ m/RSA key fingerprint is/)
        {
            $rsync->send ("yes\n");
            sleep(5);
        }
        elsif ($return =~ m/password/)
        {
            $rsync->send($password,"\n");
            $spawned = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            print "rsync answered:\n\n";
            print "$return \n";
            print "I did not expect that. EXIT\n";
            exit(1);
        }
    }

print "Sent Pw...\n";
```

That handles more different answers and can more easily be modified and debugged. But is a lot longer obviously. I prefer explicit to elegant though.

Comment: I think problem is with spawning "scp -r /home/data/ 192.168.0.1:/tmp/  " than sending the password.....the srcipt able to send the password but it is not copying the directory to the remote system..can any one help me on this

Comment: can any one tell difference between spawn($cmd) and spawn("system($cmd)")  ,which was the first point of disscussion

Comment: @ar777: Basically `spawn()` expects a shell command while `system($cmd)` is a perl command. You would not write `system(scp bla bla)` on your shell so it does not make a lot of sense when `spawn()` tries to do just that. Also i by now believe that your second problem probably is the `\r` instead of a `\n` after the password. If the answer did help you, it would be nice to accept and maybe upvote it.

Comment: :actually \n or \r are producing same result,password is being sent but directory hasn't copied

Comment: @ar777: If the password is sent but the directory is not copied than either something is wrong with your directories or there is some other input expected. Also did you as well try to remove the `=>` in your command?

Answer (score 2):

spawn expects a shell command, not Perl code. So:

```
my $exp1=Expect-> spawn($cmd)) or die;
```

The error message you see is just your shell saying it doesn't know what to do with 'system(scp...'.

And: You'll want to mask the '@'.